# Why UIScrollView don't work if you set leading and trailing anchors for subViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let labelOne: UIView = {
    let label = UIView()
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
  }()

  let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let v = UIScrollView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .cyan
    v.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000)
    return v
  }()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.addSubview(labelOne)
    
    labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
    labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
    labelOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    labelOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
  }
}
```

P.s
I know it would be better if I put the content view in a UIScrollView and build a view hierarchy in that content, but I'm genuinely wondering why this is happening

Comment: First, don't set `.contentSize` -- use auto-layout. Second, constrain the subviews to the scrollView's `.contentLayoutGuide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this...

We set the `labelOne` (red view):

- width to 1968-pts (2000 minus 16-pts on each side)
- height to 100-pts
- top, leading and trailing at 16-pts to top, leading and trailing of the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`
- bottom at 1884-pts from the bottom of the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`

So:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let labelOne: UIView = {
        let label = UIView()
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        // don't set this
        //v.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000)
        return v
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.addSubview(labelOne)

        // don't constrain directly to scrollView
        //labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        //labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        //labelOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        //labelOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        
        // if we want horizontal scrolling of 2000-pts
        //  and labelOne to have 16-pts space on each side
        labelOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000.0 - 32.0).isActive = true
        
        // labelOne height = 100
        labelOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        
        // use scrollView's Content Layout Guide
        let g = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        // labelOne 16-pts from top
        labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        
        // labelOne 16-pts from leading
        labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        
        // labelOne 16-pts from trailing (so we can scroll 2000-pts
        labelOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
        
        // if we want vertical scrolling of 2000-pts
        //  and labelOne to be 100-pts tall with 16-pts on top
        //  constrain labelOne bottom (2000 - (100 + 16)) from content guide bottom
        labelOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -(2000.0 - (100.0 + 16.0))).isActive = true

    }
}
```